# Remove duplicate combinations between two columns of Char data type in sql

Tags: sql, data-cleaning

I have two columns of Char datatype in which I want to remove duplicate combinations even if the order is different.

For Example_->

Input Data-

```
Col_1 Col_2

str_1 str_2
str_2 str_1
str_2 str_3
str_2 str_4
str_3 str_2
```

Output Data-

```
Col_1 Col_2

str_1 str_2
str_2 str_3
str_2 str_4
```

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most DBMS products support `greatest()` and `least()` functions which can be used for this:

```
select distinct least(col_1, col_2), greatest(col_1, col_2)
from the_table
order by 1
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=c8d4764b9620dd29a794d1e9e708b8c1)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the only duplicates are reversals, then the fastest method is often:

```
select col1, col2
from t
where col1 < col2 or
      not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t.col1 = t2.col2 and t.col2 = t1.col1
                 );
```

This can take advantage of an index on `(col1, col2)`, or `(col2, col1)`.

By avoiding any aggregation and using the index, this is should be the fastest method on just about database.

Answer (score 0):

You could find an answer on SQL Server in the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=3e0176a898ffefe28abc227e15d8a1ab).
A subquery `A` creates all the possible combination from the two columns. Then, only the minimum occurrence of the combination is kept in the subquery `B`. The left join has on the left side the combination with the minimum combinations. When a column from your original table is `NULL`, then it means that the opposite combination is in your table that is why the `CASE` clause is used.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN t1.Col_1 IS NULL THEN B.col_2 ELSE B.Col_1 END AS Final_Col_1,
  CASE WHEN t1.Col_1 IS NULL THEN B.col_1 ELSE B.Col_2 END AS Final_Col_2
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT *
  FROM (
        SELECT col_1, col_2
        FROM your_table
        UNION ALL
        SELECT col_2, col_1
        FROM your_table)A
  WHERE col_1< col_2)B
LEFT JOIN your_table AS t1
ON t1.Col_1=B.Col_1 AND t1.Col_2 = B.Col_2
```