# Remove Duplicates from table such that if A|B exists then B|A doesn't exist - SQL

Tags: sql

You are given a table which looks like this:

```
| COL1 | COL2 |
===============
|  A   |  B   |
|  B   |  A   |
|  C   |  B   |
|  B   |  C   |
```

The question is to remove duplicate rows, i.e., if a row = |  A   |  B   | exists then we cannot have another row = |  A   |  B   | or even a row = |  B   |  A   |.

So the result should look something like this:

```
| COL1 | COL2 |
===============
|  A   |  B   |
|  C   |  B   |
```

I am unable to think of a way to implement this in one query or even with a series of SQL queries.

Thanks.

Comment: Which database, please?

Comment: Searching I found the same answer replied here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64422759/remove-duplicate-combinations-between-two-columns-of-char-data-type-in-sql

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove duplicate combinations between two columns of Char data type in sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64422759/remove-duplicate-combinations-between-two-columns-of-char-data-type-in-sql)

Answer (score 2):

Several ways.  Here are a couple:

Standard SQL:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
       CASE WHEN col1 < col2 THEN col1 ELSE col2 END AS col1
     , CASE WHEN col1 < col2 THEN col2 ELSE col1 END AS col2
  FROM tbl
;
```

or (MySQL supports this one):

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
       LEAST(col1, col2)    AS col1
     , GREATEST(col1, col2) AS col2
  FROM tbl
;
```

There are other approaches, which have slightly different behavior.

For instance, we might want to keep ('B', 'A') if ('A', 'B') doesn't also exist.

Another thought is we could prevent this issue by correcting the data on INSERT by using similar LEAST / GREATEST logic in the INSERT (or a trigger), to be sure col1 was always less than or equal to col2.

Then add a unique constraint on (col1, col2) and a table check constraint (col1 <= col2) to prevent duplicates and reflections.

Comment: PostgreSQL also supports solution with LEAST() and GREATEST()

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct least(col_1, col_2), greatest(col_1, col_2)
from the_table
order by 1
```

Comment: Please explain your answer.